# How to include export PWD in a bash?

Tags: python, bash

I have two projects p1 and p2, and p2 depends on p1. Currently I created a virtual environment for running the program in p2, but every time I have to enter the p1's root directory and execute this in this virtual environment:

```
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`
```

Otherwise, libraries in p1 can't be imported into p2. This is fine as long as I don't exit from the current terminal. Otherwise, I have to run the 'export' command again.

Is there a way to include this export command in my bash to avoid that? If I just add the line above to my bash, it doesn't work.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's _possible_ to do what you're asking for, but it's very much the wrong thing. If you set your Python programs up correctly you can use `python setup.py develop` to point the search path for your modules at your development trees persistently with no messing around with environment variables required.

Comment: And if you do that correctly, you'll also get `python setup.py install` and all its cousins, like the tools for creating RPMs or Debian packages or so forth, for free. So very much the better approach is to abandon PYTHONPATH and use the modern packaging tools Python comes with instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I agrees with you.